# Maclaurin's series and its application conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is Maclaurin's series available when x approaches to 10000?
The value I get when I put $x=10000$ into Maclaurin's series will be similar to the right value approximately? And how should I explain this case since Maclaurin's series is a way to get an approximate value near 0.

Comment: Please show the equations that you're working with, and use MathJax to typeset them. Thank you.

Comment: I think he just wanted to know about how taylor series works.../ Is a new student who is confused

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the function you are approximating, the number of terms you include in the Maclaurin series and what exactly you mean by their values being similar. This is a question of convergence and for such a series one can find what is called the radius of convergence, which will correspond to how far from the origin one can go and the series will still converge to the function, i.e. the value of the series approaches the value of the function as the number of terms approach inifinity. There are also formulas for estimating the error when approximation within the radius of convergence. You might want to look into Taylor's formula with remainder.

Answer (score 0):

For values far away from $0$, you need to use Taylor's series rather than Maclaurin. Of course the approximation would work for 'certain' functions but you'd need a lot of terms convergence

[See this blog for more information](https://brianbabu890.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

Comment: p.s: I wrote that blog xD